# SQL query latency inconsistencies

Tags: sql, mysql

I've made a query with and without the ORDER BY clause, and it is actually much much faster without the ordering. I can't tell why, but my best guess is it's somehow related to the PRIMARY KEY index.

When I use `ORDER BY o.id ASC` / Don't order it, my query runs in around 3-4 seconds, whereas `ORDER BY o.id DESC` runs it in 30ms.

I've made indexes on `o.attached_offline_id`, `o.total_payable_amount`, `o.updated_at` and `o.status`, and o.id, u.id are primary keys, but they don't seem to speed up my query, any suggestions on how to better index my columns are very welcome, since I'm not very confident about writing performant SQL.

This is my basic query:

```
SELECT u.id as user_id, u.phone_number, o.id as order_id,
    o.total_payable_amount as amount, o.updated_at AS order_date
FROM orders o
JOIN users u ON o.user_id = u.id
WHERE o.status = 'Completed' AND o.payment_status = 'Completed' 
    AND o.total_payable_amount >= 1
    AND o.attached_offline_id IS NULL AND o.updated_at >= DATE('2023-02-01');
```

Thanks!

EDIT 1: Here is some additional info everyone requested:

1. Yes, there is a FK relation between orders and users on u.id = o.user_id.
2. `show create table orders;` and `show create table users;` results are a bit too big for me to write here, since the tables have a lot of fields and constraints, so I'll omit it here since I've mentioned the FK relation above and think that's what everyone was looking for.
3. My mysql version is 5.7.37
4. `EXPLAIN` gives me:

```sql
id|select_type|table|partitions|type  |possible_keys                                                                                                                                                                              |key              |key_len|ref               |rows  |filtered|Extra                             |
--+-----------+-----+----------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+-------+------------------+------+--------+----------------------------------+
 1|SIMPLE     |o    |          |ref   |orders_user_id_foreign,total_payable_amount,payment_status,status,orders_updated_at_IDX,orders_attached_offline_id_IDX,orders_total_payable_amount_IDX,orders_status_IDX,orders_user_id_IDX|orders_status_IDX|2      |const,const       |831158|    8.09|Using index condition; Using where|
 1|SIMPLE     |u    |          |eq_ref|PRIMARY                                                                                                                                                                                    |PRIMARY          |4      |vidyakul.o.user_id|     1|   100.0|                                  |
```

Comment: Is there foreign key added on order - users relation?

Comment: please edit your question to add (as text, not images) output of `show create table orders;` and `show create table users;` and `select version();` and `explain select ...rest of your query` (for whatever ordering you actually want, as well as whatever is being fastest); this is the minimal information needed to help with optimization questions.

Comment: The DB engine has to choose whether to use the index for the `ON` and `WHERE` conditions or for `ORDER BY`. If it uses it for `WHERE`, it may not be able to index `ORDER BY`, so the query will be slow.

Comment: Read [How MySQL Uses Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html)

Comment: Remember, too much indexes will always slows down `order by`. You can try wrapping up with an outer query like `SELECT * FROM ( SELECT u.id ..... ) ORDER BY order_id ASC`. This will speed up your query comparatively to your previous one.

Comment: You must show us the indexes; please provide SHOW CREATE TABLE.  It will be OK to leave out the columns that are not involved.

Comment: @Barmar - `ON` is usually turned into `WHERE` (See `EXPLAIN EXTENDED + WARNINGS`)  Then, the Optimizer picks which table to start with, mostly based on the list of `WHERE` clauses.  In rare cases, it will use the `ORDER BY` _instead of_ `WHERE`.  Both `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` are used _only if_ the entire `WHERE` is `=`.

Comment: @RickJames What does that have to do with my comment, which is about whether it uses it for ON/WHERE or ORDER BY? I wasn't making a distinction between ON and WHERE.

Comment: @Barmar - Sorry, I misread your Comment.

Comment: @KirsSudh - Extra indexes are ignored, the only "slow down" is in deciding which one index to use.  And that slowdown is minor.  The subquery you mention is rarely useful -- a main benefit is when the subquery has a `GROUP BY` and/or `LIMIT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a *composite* index, not lots of single-column indexes:

```
INDEX(status, payment_status, attached_offline_id,  -- "=" test
      updated_at)    -- "range" test last
```

More in my [*Index Cookbook*](https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

(PS: `DATE('2023-02-01')` can be written simply `'2023-02-01'`.)

Comment: Thanks! The Index doc really helped a lot!